# Php and SQL results

Tags: php, mysql, sql

**Solved: the issue was cause it wasnt letting me run sqli, so redefining the $conn under mysqli worked.**

```
$conn = new mysqli('IP', 'Database', 'Password', 'Username');
$query = "SELECT Auth FROM users WHERE userId = ".(int)$_SESSION['user'];
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

switch($result->fetch_assoc()['Auth']) {
case 0:
echo "Need verification";
break;
case 1:
echo "Verified";
break;
case 2:
echo "Banned";
break;
case 3:
echo "Admin";
break;
}
```

===================================

## Original Question

```
$query = "SELECT Auth FROM users ";
$result=mysqlquery($query);
if (!$result=0){
echo "Verification Pending";
}
if (!$result=1){
echo "Verified!";
}
if (!$result=2){
echo "Banned";
}
if (!$result=3){
echo "Admin";
```

i have also tried

```
$query = "SELECT Auth FROM users=";
$result = mysql_query($result);
if($result==0){
$AccountStatus = "Provided Email is already in use.";
```

and

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE Auth=";
$result=mysql_query($query);
if (!$result=0){
echo "need verification";
}
else if(!$result=1){
echo "Verified!";
}
else if (!$result=2){
echo "banned";
}
else if (!$result=3){
echo "admin";
}
```

I know its connected to the database, cause the other functions in user work perfect, and the first code I provided, it was just saying "Verification Pending", i was hoping the second code would do the trick as in the first one it was outputing in the top right corner (naturally where the code is)

If it is unclear of what I am trying to accomplish, basically different user levels. Functions work (IE, if set to 2 you cannot access your account)

PHP 5.5 (some of the features I use are only supported up-to 5.5 so I just made the whole site use it.)
Normal SQL, not SQLi

Comment: So whats the problem? Are you having a problem with the query itself, or using the output?

Comment: its not outputting, the first code was only outputting the first result. even if i changed my Auth in the db to 1,2 or 3.
Everything else is outputting and Auth is in the same database name. So i know the connection is fine.

Comment: You need to look up some basic PHP tutorials. You've provided three different pieces of code, none of which are slightly correct, and all of which mean different things, its impossible to know exactly what you want.

Comment: in my users table, there is a Auth section, and when a account is created it is defaulted to 0. Once the account is verified, it is set to 1.
Just trying to make a out put code for user profiles that displays "Needs Verification" or "Verified"
along with if they are banned or if its an admin account.

I have provided several different versions of code because I have tried several different methods to accomplish my goal.

Comment: *"Solved: the issue was cause it wasnt letting me run sqli, so redefining the $conn under mysqli worked."* - That isn't the only thing wrong with your code; did you know that?

Comment: oh god I know, I am going through trying to fix it up as much as I can. Like I said the stuff I am using is so out dated, its hard running new functions with all of it. (its for a game from 2007 that isnt live anymore but the devs released the source, and hooking up a registration page an all when non of its functions work past php 5.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a serious problem with your logic. `if(!$result=0)` is wrong in many ways (`=` is for assignment not comparison, `!$result` is inverting `$result`).

You also can't access a result object like that, you need to ask it to return it in the format you want.

Try using a switch:

```
switch($result->fetch_assoc()['Auth']) {
    case 0:
        echo "Need verification";
        break;
    case 1:
        echo "Verified";
        break;
    case 2:
        echo "Banned";
        break;
    case 3:
        echo "Admin";
        break;
}
```

The above will not solve your issue unless you fix your query first though. Firstly, you need to switch to mysqli_* or PDO, since mysql_* functions are deprecated, heres an example of what you would put before the switch:

```
$query = "SELECT Auth FROM users WHERE userId = " . (int)$_SESSION['user'];
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
```

If the userId is not an integer, then you'll need to use prepared statements. `$conn` needs to contain your connection object.

Comment: $query = ("SELECT Auth FROM users WHERE userId".$_SESSION['user']);
$result = mysqli_query($query);

Comment: so i am using mysqli, and my userId is set to Int.
Still throwing issues on the switch line, and each case line.

Comment: What errors? No help if I can't see them. Your query probably failed, or your connection is not valid.

Comment: Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, resource given in ../user.php on line 17

// // // Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object in ../user.php on line 19
17 is     $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query); // 19 is the switch.

Comment: Your connection failed. You need to create a connection using `$conn = new mysqli('ip', 'user', 'password', 'dbname');`

Comment: the top of my page I have it require_once 'dbconnect.php' .. this has the connection info, do i have to redefine it?

Comment: oh, well it does work. yeah the issue was cause it wasnt letting me run sqli, so redefining it fixed it. Now I am wondering how to get the echo to the location I need it. can I lable the input $something, than add it to the location needed.

Answer (score -1):

try this code see if it help

```
$userId = $_SESSION['user'] ; 

$query = ("SELECT Auth FROM users Where userId='$userId"); 

$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query); 

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$result = $row['Auth'] ; 


if (intval($result)===0){
echo "need verification";
}
else if(intval($result)===1){
echo "Verified!";
}
else if (intval($result)===2){
echo "banned";
}
else if (intval($result) ===3){
echo "admin";
}
```

or you can use a switch statement as said already

Comment: This is completely wrong; syntactically, logically and is not even relevant or related to the question at all.

Comment: It still does not answer the question, the OP does not want to count the rows.

Comment: that was my bad, I forgot to edit that part of the line. I just copied it from another function i am using, and CTRL+Z a few to many times when i was just trying to show what i have tried.

Comment: I did end up using a switch, so I thank you for your feed back:)